# Display local PDF with ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-pdf-viewer

I am trying to display a PDF with ng2-pdf-viewer but it does not show. The PDF is on my computer, inside the project in the assets folder.
[my src folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWUYP.png)
Here is my html

```
<h1> Angular 10 PDF Viewer</h1>

<div class="container">
  <textarea title="pdf" [(ngModel)] = "pdfUrl"></textarea>
  <label>PDF HoNOS</label>
  <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfUrl"
              [original-size]="false"
  ></pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

And my .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GenerationPdfService } from '../generation-pdf.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fin-formulaire',
  templateUrl: './fin-formulaire.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fin-formulaire.component.css']
})
export class FinFormulaireComponent {
  constructor(private generationPdfService : GenerationPdfService) { }
  pdfUrl = "../assets/TemplatePDFHonos.pdf";
}
```

I dont understand why it isnt working, it is supposed to be easy but I am new with angular, ts, html so maybe I made a dumb mistake

I also tried to use assets/TemplatePDFHonos.pdf as pdfUrl but neither of them work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view PDF files I use **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer**

> npm i ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Its use is very similar

```
< ngx-extended-pdf-viewer  [src] =" 'assets/example.pdf' " useBrowserLocale =" true " > </ ngx-extended-pdf-viewer >
```

I have it in a project and have had no problems. I leave you the page where you can see more examples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

From what i get from ur project structure ,I think the path u r giving is wrong.

Please try `../../assets/` or `./../../assets/`

Since the above code is not working iam just describing the steps here.

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfurl" [render-text]="true" [original-size]="false" [fit-to-page]="true"[zoom]="zoom" [zoom-scale]="'page-width'" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"></pdf-viewer>
```

`zoom and zoom-scale` is used for taking zoom functions.

Please try to add these styles also.Since sometimes eventhough the content is rendered,Due to '0' height in parent ,it's not visible.

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"
```

In your Module Please Import the below.(Wherever your Shown component is declared.If component is declared in appmodule,import it there or any responsible module)

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
imports:[
      //For new NG2 PDF VIEWER
  PdfViewerModule
]
```

Please add more details even if all these dont works.

Comment: I tried the paths you suggested but none of them worked sadly, I also tried with absolute path but did not work either.